# make homebutton call onFinish()

Tags: android

all i want to do is call onFinish() when the homebutton is pressed, i want to do this so i always enter the main activity when opening my app, i dont want the user to jump back to where he left of(i know this is a bad concept in most cases but for my app it makes more sense to always enter into main activity)

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to happen is that all of your *child* Activities to have the android:noHistory=true attribute.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

> android:noHistory : 
>   Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and
>   finished (its finish() method called)
>   when the user navigates away from it
>   and it's no longer visible on screen —
>   "true" if it should be finished, and
>   "false" if not. The default value is
>   "false".
>
> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the
>   activity stack for the task, so the
>   user will not be able to return to it.
>
> This attribute was introduced in API Level 3.

Answer (score -2):

Well, i can try answering that, "always enter the main activity when opening my app", if you are using onPause(), onResume(), onStop(), etc, then either remove these, then it will always be the first activity that will load, or explicitly call finish() on onPause().

Comment: Agreeing with Falmarri here. I am pretty sure removing on[Pause|Resume|Stop] has nothing to do with the activity history stack or navigation.

Comment: no i dont think so either, and i cannot just call finish in my onpause, i do this now but it causes other problems.